# Using source(functions.R) in r script with docker

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

I've created an R script named `analysis.R` that uses custom functions from `functions.R` When I run the script locally using `source(./functions.R)` it works but when I run a docker image with the files I get the error

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> source -> file
In addition: Warning message:

In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file './functions.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

I looked inside the docker image and `functions.R` was copied to the container along with the `analysis.R` script.

Here's the lines from the Dockerfile used to copy the scripts

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.2

RUN mkdir /home

COPY analysis.R /home/analysis.R
COPY functions.R /home/functions.R
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance?

Comment: How are you executing this? Are you getting a shell on the container and executing it manually? If so, then where are you in the container when you execute it?

Comment: I'm executing it directly from terminal on mac.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the working directory in the docker file solves this problem.

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.2

WORKDIR /home

COPY analysis.R analysis.R
COPY functions.R functions.R
```

Comment: this allowed you to use the above `source` command?